# Python script doesnt work in differents virtual machines

Tags: python, python-3.5

I have a script that clean logs in determinate path.

This script works in one virtual machine but when i export to another one, this script doesn't work. The versions of python are the same:

```
[ec2-user@host1 h]$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.1
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jenk.py", line 54, in <module>
    dicta = dict(path)
  File "jenk.py", line 51, in dict
    dicto[elem] = { (dirs['Subdir'][elem]['Path']) : (dirs['Subdir'][elem]['Num_Subdir']) }
KeyError: 'Path'
```

This is the code:

```
def PathToDict(path):
    st = os.lstat(path)
    result = {}
    if S_ISDIR(st.st_mode):
        result['Path'] = path
        result['Subdir'] = {
            name: PathToDict(path+'/'+name)
            for name in os.listdir(path)}
        result['Num_Subdir'] = int(len([i for i, j, k in os.walk(path)]))
#        result['RealSize'] = subprocess.check_output(['du','-sh', path]).split()[0].decode('utf-8')

    else:
        result['type'] = 'file'
    return result

dirs = PathToDict(path)


#Getting new dict with clean info with name of dir and number of dirs

def dict(path):

    dicto = {}
    for elem in dirs['Subdir']:
        dicto[elem] = { (dirs['Subdir'][elem]['Path']) : (dirs['Subdir'][elem]['Num_Subdir']) }
    return dicto
```

Any idea? COuld be problem of modules?

Comment: How did you define the S_ISDIR method?

Comment: stat.S_ISDIR(mode)

    Return non-zero if the mode is from a directory.

Answer (score 0):

there is not 'Path' in elem.

Try to debug

```
print(dirs['Subdir'][elem])
```

or use

```
dirs['Subdir'][elem].get('Path')
```

Comment: But my question is why there is not Path in one host while in the other one works.. I'll try this debug..

Comment: There is Path in the debug output ```{'Path': '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/postgresql-backup-recovery/builds/330', 'Num_Subdir': 1, 'Subdir': {'log': {'type': 'file'}, 'build.xml': {'type': 'file'}, 'changelog.xml': {'type': 'file'},```

Comment: I checked that Path exist, but is not an subelement. The output are different in both machines but idk why..

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might make stuff os dependent is that you manually join a file path in

```
 name: PathToDict(path+'/'+name)
```

However, that '/' might not be valid on all devices. Instead it is better to use the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html) module in python to join paths. This will automatically select the correct separator.

```
name: PathToDict(os.path.join(path,name))
```

This would at least make that part of the code platform independent.

Additionally, passing your input through [os.path.normpath](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.path.html) will make sure that the input gets correctly parsed to something that is readable on your platform.

Comment: '/' should be valid in all devices because are the same SO and the path are exactly.. I dont understand. Could be problem of Python's modules version or similar?

Comment: Ah sorry, when you said different virtual machines I also assumed that they ran on different OS-ses.